# ASP.Net Compilation Error for GridView OnPageIndexChanging event

Tags: asp.net

Before I add this codes, I got error about GridView fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled and same for Sorting. So I add this event codes then I got Compilation error say that, "CS1061: 'ASP.serveredit_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging' and no extension method 'GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.serveredit_aspx' could be found". However I already have that event code in C# as well. Please Help

Here my GridView property codes,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewServer" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridViewServer_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ServerName" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" onrowcancelingedit="GridViewServer_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridViewServer_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridViewServer_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridViewServer_RowUpdating">
```

The C# code behind for this event,

```
private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                break;

            case SortDirection.Descending:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }

    protected void gridViewServer_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewServer.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridViewServer.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gridViewServer_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GridViewServer.DataSource as DataTable;

        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

            GridViewServer.DataSource = dataView;
            GridViewServer.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your codebehind please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize the gridViewServer_PageIndexChanging and gridViewServer_Sorting are lower case. I forgot to capitalize it.